# Android Facebook SDK - AppInviteDialog not using App Login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently updated my Android App to Facebook SDK 4.0.1.

As shown in the official Facebook documentation I am utilizing the new AppInviteDialog to integrate App Invitations, which is working fine most of the time.

The problem arises when the user is logged in via the Facebook App and is not logged in in his browser. In this case the AppInviteDialog shows the Facebook Login screen.

Is there any way to open up the Invite Friend Dialog in the Facebook App, or a way to transfer the login in the App to the Browser.

Comment: By default the invite dialog should switch over to the Facebook app. What version of the Facebook app are you using?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. The device i was testing with was running quite an old version of the Facebook app. Updating fixed the issue.